# jQuery: A problem with .each function

Tags: jquery

I send to the javascript an array like:

[image]

```
 $.each(data, function (value, name) {
    $('#visitStart').append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(value));
 });
```

and as a result I see that the visitStart input is filled by values from 0 to 241. Why ?

Comment: Which kind of data are you trying to parse? XML? Json? Can you post the code around this each statement?

Comment: did you try to display that json objects in the browser so that you can be sure that the returned structure fits the parsing function?

Comment: Images are next to useless. Next time, please post proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$.each sends an index, and value into the callback function - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
 $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
    $('#visitStart').append($('<option></option>').val(obj.value).html(obj.value));
 });
```

Comment: when I try to get the 'obj.value' I see 'undefined'

Comment: @Tony, then your object isn't what the screenshot suggests (to me). Could you run `console.log(data)` and show us the output in Firebug or Chrome Console?